# How to make the textfield move up when keyboard covers it up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, textview, textfield

I have an application in which I have 2 textfields and a textview. When I click on the first textfield my keyboard popsup and theirs is no problem but when I type in the second textfield my keyboard popsup and covers the textfield.

I want that when I click on the second text field, the textfield should move up little bit so that I can type in and I have a textview. But I have written code for textview so that when I type in textview it automatically moves.

The problem is with textfield. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the link below - the solution is written by Micheal Tyson. It addresses UITableView and UIScrollView, can be easily changed and works just as a drop-in component. I'm using it and it works well.

[A drop-in universal solution for moving text fields out of the way of the keyboard](http://atastypixel.com/blog/a-drop-in-universal-solution-for-moving-text-fields-out-of-the-way-of-the-keyboard/)

Comment: Hi delirus, i have gone through the link you mentioned in your answer but i have a problem ,the keyboard remains intact through the entire  application.It does not resigns even if the textfield has endediting

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a [UITableViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Otherwise implement `UITextFieldDelegate` and move your UIView to the desired position in the `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method.

Comment: +1 for recommending UITableViewController - I can not emphasize enough how much more convenient it is when implementing forms.

Comment: This is not the best answer since textFieldDidBeginEditing can be called if the user uses a Bluetooth keyboard, and there is no need for any scrolling.  YOu should instead watch keyboard notification events to detect the presence of a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Create two methods like given below , first one is for bringing the view  slightly upwards, and second one is to bring the view to its original position back

First method:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];

self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.view.transform, 0, -175);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Second method:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];

self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.view.transform, 0, 175);
[UIView commitAnimations];

[self.destext resignFirstResponder];
```

Call these  methods on textfieldEditingDidbegin and DidEndonExit

Answer (score 0):

Add the view to a `UIScrollView`. Then use the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods to set the `contentOffset` of the `scrollView` when textField is tapped. Reset the `contentOffset` when the user has finished entering text.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious one that you've probably tried already, but one that took me a while to latch onto, is to change from landscape to portrait.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple subclass of UIView containing UITextView and a send button that moves up when keyboard shows and moves down when keyboard hides. In addition to that, UITextView resizes according to the amount of text in it.

Have a look at here:

https://github.com/kerrygrover/KBTextView

[image]